# autowire dependency exception ,

Tags: java, javabeans, autowired

> DEBUG [http-bio-8004-exec-3] DispatcherServlet.processRequest(954) |
>   Could not complete request
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'contactFormController': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   com.crisil.cmd.webapp.controller.ContactFormController.setContactListService(com.crisil.cmd.service.ContactListService);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'contactListService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   com.crisil.cmd.service.impl.ContactListServiceImpl.setContactListDao(com.crisil.cmd.dao.ContactListDao);
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)

the above code is from my project which is in production ,so there are no chance of java errors  (@AUTOWIRED ) OR annotation based errors , my question is , is there any other possibility of getting this type of error .

Comment: Please share your java code too

Comment: "nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback" This seems like the actual reason to me. Somehow, your code is not able to read the Kafka Dependency on your project environment. Try updating the dependency on prod.